# How to use SQL coalesce with a null whole fetched row

Tags: sql, db2-400, rpgle

The case I am trying to solve is this: for every row in a table another row from a second table might exist, so I need all data from the row of the first table and the data from the row of the second table if present.

I know I can use data structures as host variables to gather all data from a row in a table. So, my select is this:

```
select
    t1.*
   ,t2.*
into
    :dst1
   ,:dst2
from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t2.key=t1.key
;
```

where dst1 and dst2 are data structures respectively like table1 and table2 records' format. Pretty simple.

Now, the point is how to catch null result when a row for that key doesn't exist in the second table. In that case I would like to have the corresponding data structure initialized, but coalesce works on one field at a time and I haven't been able to find another solution.

Is there a way to obtain this result?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I think only way here is to apply coalesce to all fields from table t2 like this coalesce(t2.field1, t1.field1).

Comment: I wouldn't name every single field, because both record formats have a huge number of them.
Coalesce is not an obliged solution, if at least another one is possible.

Comment: `SELECT *` isn't something that should be used in production.  Do you really need all the current fields?  Even if you do, you should 99% or the time explicitly name them.   It's not difficult to get a list of the current columns..

`select listagg(column_name concat ',') as columnList
from qsys2.syscolumns
where table_name = 'MYTABLE' and table_schema = 'MYLIBRARY'`

Comment: Yes, you are right, definitely, probably I will end up naming the fields I really need. Nonetheless, we are used to get the whole record format even if not all fields are needed, because this is what CHAIN operation code does and it might be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to deal with this is to use indicator variables. It looks like this:

```
dcl-ds hs    Qualified;
  field1 ...
  field2 ...
endds;

dcl-s hsind  Int(5) Dim(2);

exec sql
  select *
    into :hs:hsind
    from table
    fetch first row only;
```

Note, there is no comma (,) between :hs and :hsind as this is part of the same variable assignment. :hsind is an indicator variable, and in this case is an array of `Int(5)` with the same number of elements as the host data structure :hs has fields. The indicator variable will contain a 0 if the value in the associated field in :hs is good, or -1 if it is null. So in our example above: If hs.field1 is good, and hs.field2 is null, then hsind(1) = 0, and hsind(1) = -1. Other values mean other things like data mapping error (-2), or string truncation (positive number with original length of string).

So in your example, use something like this:

```
select
    t1.*
   ,t2.*
into
    :dst1:dst1ind
   ,:dst2:dst2ind
from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t2.key=t1.key
;
```

Where `dst1ind` is an array if Int(5) with the same number of elements as `dst1` has subfields, similarly for `dst2ind`. Then after your selection, just check `dst2ind(1) >= 0`, and you have a good select. Notice that you will need to make sure that `select into` only returns a single row, or you will get errors about that.

Comment: I tried it, but I thought in case a whole DS was filled in, a single indicator was enough to signal that the record format was found or not, whilst you are telling me an indicator for each field is needed in any case. This is a solution, though the number of fields must be known in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need an indicator for each field in the data structure, and yes, you must know the number of fields in advance. But if you do not use `select *`, which is a best practice anyway, then you will know the number of fields.